how to import a .shp file on a react js project and display it on a leaflet map
how to import a .shp file on a react js project and display the contents of the shp file on a leaflet map
tried converting the shp file into Json and geojson then import them into the project but failed to get results on the map.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
